# Bootstrap dropdown with button item and close programatically on button click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a Bootstrap 2.3.2 button dropdown menu. I have checkboxes and a button inside the dropdown. I want to leave the dropdown open if I click any of the checkboxes and especially if I click the button. Once the action behind the button completes I want to manually close the dropdown. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="order_item_id" value="<?=$item->id?>">
    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-container="body"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i> Create tasks <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks1" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks1">Order material</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks2" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks2">Order accessories</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks3" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks3">Order CNC parts</label></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks4" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks4">SW development (confirm delivery)</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks5" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks5">HW development (confirm delivery)</label></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks6" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks7">Order ALU</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks7" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks8">Mill CNC parts</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks8" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks9">Anodize</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="create_tmpl_tasks9" id="form_create_tmpl_tasks10">Laser gravure</label></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="action"><button type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-create">Create</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have managed to disable dropdown close if I click on checkboxes with this code:

```
$('.dropdown-menu input, .dropdown-menu label').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If I include the button in this selector also, then the button won't receive click events, and that I don't want. I want to execute some AJAX call on button click and when I get result I would like to close the dropdown. Something like this:

```
$('.btn-create').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            btn.button('reset');
            // close drop down here
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            btn.button('reset');       
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuNA7/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `.click()` adds handlers to be invoked in order. If you add the `.btn-create` selector to the first handler to stop propagation, then the `stopPropagation()` code is being invoked before the handler that is specific to `.btn-create`. However, if you include `e.stopPropagation();` in the click handler for `.btn-create`, then it should work as expected.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/vuNA7/3/

Comment: Great thanks. What about on closing dropdown once the code on button click is executed?

Comment: Declare a reference to your dropdown in the main body of the `.click()` handler, then pass that reference to the success handler of your `$.ajax()` call. I don't know bootstrap, so I can't tell you the exact idiom to grab that reference, nor what kinds of error conditions you may encounter, but I'd guess you'll want to make sure the dropdown isn't already closed before firing off a close event.